# Find a Quick Match Email Regular Expression

Tags: python

```
solution:[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)* is a good choice
```

I am using a regular expression like the below to match email addresses in a file:

```
email = re.search('(\w+-*[.|\w]*)*@(\w+[.])*\w+',line)
```

When used on a file like the following, my regular expression works well:

```
mlk407289715@163.com    huofenggib  wrong in get_gsid
mmmmmmmmmm776@163.com   rouni816161 wrong in get_gsid
```

But when I use it on a file like below, my regular expression runs unacceptably slowly:

```
9b871484d3af90c89f375e3f3fb47c41e9ff22  mingyouv9gueishao@163.com
e9b845f2fd3b49d4de775cb87bcf29cc40b72529e   mlb331055662@163.com
```

And when I use the regular expression from [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), it still runs very slowly.

I need a solution and want to know what's wrong.

Comment: Define "slow". And are you certain it's the regular expression that is the bottleneck?

Comment: it's my code http://pastebin.com/6vUBxLZV  you can try it,when it runs,it stagnate in regular expression match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when regular expressions are slow, it is due to [catastrophic bactracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  This can happen in your regex because of the nested repetition during in the following section:

```
(\w+-*[.|\w]*)*
```

If you can work on this section of the regex to remove the repetition from within the parentheses you should see a substantial speed increase.

However, you are probably better of just searching for an email regex and seeing how other people have approached this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem with backtracking. Read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for more information.

You might want to split the line and work with the part containing an @:

```
pattern = '(\w+-*[.|\w]*)*@(\w+[.])*\w+'
line = '9b871484d3af90c89f375e3f3fb47c41e9ff22  mingyouv9gueishao@163.com'
for element in line.split():
    if '@' in element:
        g = re.match(pattern, element)
        print g.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to search StackOverflow to see if your question has already been discussed.

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

This one, from that discussion, looks like a good one to me:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*
```

Comment: yes, your works,and mine maybe like other said is with the catastrophic bactracking